# Prob. 16 (c), Sec. 6.2, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS, 4th ed: If $f^\prime(x)\to b$ as $x \to \infty$, then $f(x)/x \to b$. How?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 16, Sec. 6.1, in the book *Introduction To Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $f \colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and assume that $f^\prime(x) \to b$ as $x \to \infty$.

> (a) Show that for any $h > 0$, we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} \big( f(x+h) - f(x) \big)/h = b$.

> (b) Show that if $f(x) \to a $ as $x \to \infty$, then $b = 0$.

> (c) Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \big( f(x)/x \big) = b$.

Here is Definition 4.3.10 in Bartle & Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $(a, \infty) \subseteq A$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. We say that $L \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit of $f$ as $x \to \infty$, and write
> $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f = L \qquad \mbox{ or } \qquad \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L, $$
> if given any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $K = K(\varepsilon) > a$ such that for any $x > K$, then $\lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon$.

I think I'm clear on Parts (a) and (b).

How to do Part (c)?

Here is my attempt at Part (c):

> As $f^\prime$ is defined for all $x$ in $(0, \infty)$ and as $f^\prime(x) \to b$ as $x \to \infty$, so given any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a $K \colon= K(\varepsilon/3) > 0$ such that for any $x > K$, we have
> $$ \left\lvert f^\prime(x) - b \right\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}. \tag{0}$$

> In particular, for $\varepsilon = 1$, there exists a real number $K_0 \colon= K(1) > 0$ such that for any $x > K_0$, we have $$ \left\lvert f^\prime(x) - b \right\rvert < 1.$$
> So for any $x > K_0$, we also have
> $$ \left\lvert f^\prime(x) \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert f^\prime(x) - b \right\rvert + \lvert b \rvert < 1 + \lvert b \rvert, $$
> and thus
> $$ \left\lvert f^\prime(x) \right\rvert < 1 + \lvert b \rvert \tag{1} $$
> for any real number $x > K_0$.

> Now let $M$ be any real number such that
> $$ M > \max \left\{ \ K, K_0  \ \right\}. \tag{2}$$

> Let us take $x$ to be any real number such that
> $$x >  \max\left\{ \ M, \frac{3 \big( \lvert f(M) \rvert + 1 \big) }{\varepsilon }, \frac{3 M \big( \lvert b \rvert + 1 \big)}{  \varepsilon } \ \right\}. \tag{3}. $$

> Then as $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[ M, x]$ and differentiable on the open interval $( M, x)$, so there exists a real number $c_x \in (M, x)$ such that
> $$ f(x) - f(M) = (x-M) f^\prime \left( c_x \right),  $$
> and then
> $$ f(x) = f(M) + (x-M) f^\prime \left( c_x \right),  $$
> which implies that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \  \left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{x} - b \right\rvert \\ 
> &=  \left\lvert \frac{ f(M) + (x-M) f^\prime \left( c_x \right) }{x} - b \right\rvert \\
> &= \left\lvert f^\prime \left( c_x \right) - b + \frac{f(M)}{x} - \frac{M f^\prime\left(c_x\right)}{x} \right\rvert \\
> &\leq \left\lvert f^\prime \left( c_x \right) - b \right\rvert +  \frac{ \left\lvert f(M) \right\rvert }{x}  + \frac{ M \left\lvert f^\prime\left(c_x\right) \right\rvert }{x} \\
> & \ \ \ \mbox{ [ Note that our choice of $K$, $K_0$, and $M$ in (0), (1), and (2) above, respectively, implies that $x > 0$ also. ] } \\
> &< \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{ \left\lvert f(M) \right\rvert }{x}  + \frac{M}{x} \left( \lvert b \rvert + 1 \right) \\ 
> & \ \ \  \mbox{ [ using (2), and then (0) and (1) above ] } \\ 
> & < \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{\lvert f(M)\rvert \varepsilon}{3 \big( \lvert f(M) \rvert + 1 \big) } + \frac{\varepsilon}{3 \left( \lvert b \rvert + 1 \right) } \left( \lvert b \rvert + 1 \right) \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using (3) above ] }\\
> &\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{ \varepsilon }{ 3 } + \frac{\varepsilon }{3} \\
> &= \varepsilon.
> \end{align}
> $$

> Let us put
> $$ M^* \colon= \max\left\{ \ M, \frac{3 \big( \lvert f(M) \rvert + 1 \big) }{\varepsilon }, \frac{3 M \big( \lvert b \rvert + 1 \big)}{  \varepsilon } \ \right\}. \tag{4}. $$

> Thus we have shown that, for any given real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a real number $M^* > 0$ such that
> $$ \left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{x} - b \right\rvert < \varepsilon $$
> for every real number $x > M^*$. Therefore
> $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = b, $$
> as required.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it rigorous and clear enough too? Or, are there any problems in it?

Comment: There is a much shorter proof of c). Are you willing to consider it?

Comment: Seems like a proof of the Stolz formula for functional limits… Or maybe we could prove this in an easier way.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your comment. Yes, why not? Hopefully that proof will be "elementary" enough. But can you please check my work and and give your valuable opinion on whether or not my proof is correct and rigorous enough?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood The proof I have given in my answer is elementary. However, if you insist on an $\epsilon, K$ argument then your proof is OK.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you so much for reviewing and commenting on and answering my question. One more favor please! Can we also connect using phone (esp. WhatsApp)? My cellphone number (also for WhatsApp) is 0092 334 541 7958. Can I have yours too?

Comment: Apply L'Hospital's Rule on $f(x) /x$

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps for  a neater proof:

1. If $a_n=f(n+1)-f(n)$ then $a_n \to b$ by MVT.
2. It follows that $\frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n} n \to b$. Conclude that $\frac {f(n)} n \to b$ as $ n \to \infty$.
3. If $n \leq x \leq n+1$ then $\frac {f(x)} x= \frac {f(x)-f(n)} x+\frac {f(n)} n \frac n x$. Use MVT again to conclude that $|f(x)-f(n)| <|b|+1$ as long as $n$ is large enough (and $n \leq x \leq n+1$). This shows that $\frac {f(x)-f(n)} x \to 0$. Also, $\frac {f(n)} n \frac n x \to b$. Hence $\frac {f(x)} x \to b$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The first two steps therein are absolutely clear, but I'd be grateful if you could add some more detail in Step 3, esp. on how $\lvert f(x) - f(b) \rvert < \lvert b \rvert +1$ holds.

Comment: I think that should be $|f(x)-f(n)|<|n|+1$

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood J_P is right. I typed $f(b)$ for $f(n)$.